# Is it possible to position elements in a cell of grid pane free in Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx, position, cell, scenebuilder, gridpane

I have a "problem".
I want add 3 Radio Buttons in a cell of a grid pane. I can do that but I wonder how can I change position the radio buttons in the scene builder. So that one radio button is at the top of the cell the other in the middle and the last one at the top of the cell. Is this possible in the scene builder?

So in this picture I would the black drawn radiobuttons.

[image]

Comment: Wrap them in a `VBox`? But why not put them in different cells?

Comment: @Jamens_D Do you mean putting a VBox in the cell? I want to have them in one cell because I have for each row a different information so I dont want to have 3 rows/columns just because I have 3 radiobuttons

Comment: Yes, put the `VBox` in the cell. The other solution would still work fine, just give the other controls in the same "row" a `rowSpan` of `3`.

Comment: @James_D can I change to rowspan on the right side of the scene builder? Because I can somehow only change it when i rightclick on the radiobutton and than increase it. But do you know why I can only increase the size to the right and not on the left if I use a GridPane or even a VBox.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking in that last comment.

Comment: if you have for eg. a VBox you have an allignment for eg TOP_LEFT. And than if you have an element lets say a button in the VBox and you try to change the width of the button, you somehow can only change to width of the right side. The button is fixed at the TOP_LEFT position so I can't wheter increase the top height or left width